# Split large JSON file into batches of 100 at a time to run through an API

Tags: python, json

I am so close to being done with this tool I am developing, but as a junior developer with NO senior programmer to work with I am stuck. I have a script in python that takes data from our data base converts it to JSON to be run through an Address validation API, I have it all working, but the fact is that the API only accepts 100 objects at a time. I need to basically break up the file with X objects into batches of 100 to be run then stored into the same output file. Here is the snippit of my script structure:

```
for row in rows:

    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['input_id'] = str(row.INPUT_ID)
    d['addressee'] = row.NAME
    d['street'] = row.ADDRESS
    d['city'] = row.CITY
    d['state'] = row.STATE
    d['zipcode'] = row.ZIP
    d['candidates'] = row.CANDIDATES
    obs_list.append(d)

json.dump(obs_list, file)

ids_file = '.csv'

cur.execute(input_ids)

columns = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

ids_input = cur.fetchall()

#ids_csv = csv.writer(with open('.csv','w',newline=''))

with open('.csv','w',newline='') as f:

    ids_csv = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')

    ids_csv.writerow(columns)

    ids_csv.writerows(ids_input)

print('Run through API')

url = 'https://api.'

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

this  is where i assume i need to do the loop to break it up

```
with open('.json', 'r') as run:

    dict_run = run.readlines()

    dict_ready = (''.join(dict_run))

#lost :(
    for object in dict_ready:

        # do something with object to only run 100 at a time

        r = requests.post(url, data=dict_ready, headers=headers)

ss_output = r.text

output = 'C:\\Users\\TurnerC1\\Desktop\\ss_output.json'

with open(output,'w') as of:

    of.write(ss_output)
```

at the moment I have about 4,000 of these in a file to be run through the API that only accepts 100 at a time. Im sure there is an easy answer, I am just burnt out doing this by myself lol. Any help is greatly appreciated.

sample json:

```
[
        {
            "street":"1 Santa Claus",
            "city":"North Pole",
            "state":"AK",
            "candidates":10
        },
        {
            "addressee":"Apple Inc",
            "street":"1 infinite loop",
            "city":"cupertino",
            "state":"CA",
            "zipcode":"95014",
            "candidates":10
        }
    ]'
```

Comment: This question could be greatly improved by focusing it on the immediate question and making the code a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- containing only the smallest possible code to reproduce your actual problem. Your "actual problem", arguably, doesn't have anything to do with JSON or HTTP POSTs or APIs or CSVs at all -- including which details makes it both harder for readers to follow and makes answers less useful to folks with a similar underlying problem but different surrounding circumstances -- but is about taking a long list and splitting it up into a bunch of short ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as your second chunk of code

```
with open('.json', 'r') as run:
    dict_run = json.loads(run)

ss_output=[]
for i in range(0,len(dict_ready),100):
    # do something with object to only run 100 at a time
    dict_ready=json.dumps(dict_run[i:i+100])
    r = requests.post(url, data=dict_ready, headers=headers)
    ss_output.extend(r.json())

output = 'C:\\Users\\TurnerC1\\Desktop\\ss_output.json'

with open(output,'w') as of:

    json.dump(ss_output,of)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, you have a range of objects, and you want to break it up into subsets, each of which is no more than 100 items.

Assuming that `dict_ready` is a list of objects (if it's not, modify your code to make it so):

```
count = 100
subsets = (dict_ready[x:x + count] for x in range(0, len(dict_ready), count))
for subset in subsets:
    r = requests.post(url, data=subset, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

So assuming the rest of your code works, this will give the api a break every 100 rows for 10 secs. You will need to import the time module.

```
    for i, object in enumerate(dict_ready):
        r = requests.post(url, data=dict_ready, headers=headers)
        if i%100==0:
            time.sleep(10)
```